# PHP Array Zeros except for one, extract that value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with values that change from time to time.  It will usually look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 9876 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 )
```

All of the Values will be 0 except for one (index location will change).
If more than one value is greater than 0, I need to execute a specific command.
Else, if only one value is greater than 0, I need to take that value and pass it to a specific command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?PHP

$array = array(
"1" => "0",
"2" => "0",
"3" => "0",
"4" => "24",
"5" => "0");

$zero_plus_keys = 0;
$zero_plus_val  = array();

foreach($array as $key => $val)
{
    if($val > 0)
    {
        $zero_plus_keys++;
        $zero_plus_val = array($key,$val);
    }
}

if($zero_plus_keys == 1)
{
    echo "In array '".$zero_plus_val[0]."' key contains Greater than zero value. the value is = '".$zero_plus_val[1]."'";
}
elseif($zero_plus_keys > 1)
{
    echo "More keys Greater than zero(0)";
}
else
{
    echo "All keys contains zero(0)s only...";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new array containing only the non-null values. [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) without callback will return all elements which do not evaluate to `FALSE`.:

```
$a = array(...);
$values = array_filter($a);

switch(count($values)) {
  case 0: echo 'All 0!'; break;
  case 1: specificCommandWithValue($values[0]); break;
  default: executeSpecificCommand(); break;
}
```

If you have false-y values, you want to keep (`FALSE`, `NULL`, `'0'`, `''`), pass a callback which does strict value comparison: `function($el) { return $el !== 0; }`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$count  =0;
foreach($array as $item){

   if($item !=0){
      $count = $count+1;
    }
}
if($count > 1){

//execute a specific command
}elseif($count == 1){
  // take that value and pass it to a specific command
}else{
  //all value are zero 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is @NullPointer's answer, but I added in a variable to hold "that value".

```
$count  =0;
$nonzero = null;
foreach($array as $item){

   if($item !=0){
      $count = $count+1;
      $nonzero = $item;
    }
}
if($count > 1){

//execute a specific command
}elseif($count == 1){
  specific_command($nonzero);
}else{
  //all value are zero 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$array = 'your array';

function Find($array){

```
 $count = 0;
 $needle = -1;                
 foreach($array as $item){
         if($item > 0){
               $count++;
               $needle = $item;
         } 
         if($count > 1)
                return -1; //error as number of non-zeroes greater than 1
 }
 if($count > 0)
      return $needle;  //returns the required single non-zero item
 return 0; // returns zero if nothing is found
```

}

$return = Find($array);

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun :P

```
$array = array_flip(array_flip($array));
sort($array);
if (count($array) > 2) moreThanOne();
else onlyOne($array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array and if there is only one use `current()` to get it:

```
if(count($n = array_filter($array)) == 1) {
    execute_command(current($n));
} else {
    execute_command();
}
```